# how to optimize sequential processing of network requests between two servers in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I would like to make hundreds of API requests sequentially to the webserver "A", executed one after the other to not to clogg the server.
On each response from this server, I need to send this response to webserver "B" for processing but the condition is that I cannot send multiple requests to server B at once, but only one at a time.

NOTE: I don't want to delay requests to webserver A while a request is still pending to webserver B.

How should I change my code to meet these conditions? (my current code ignores the condition about not sending multiple requests at once to webserver B)

```
import { from, of, defer } from 'rxjs';
import { concatAll } from 'rxjs/operators'

const source = defer(() => {

  const webserverA_req1 = defer(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log('webserver A request #1 run');
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('a')
      }, 500) 
    });
  });

  const webserverA_req2 = defer(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log('webserver A request #2 run');
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('b')
      }, 2500)
    });
  });

  const webserverA_req3 = defer(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log('webserver A request #3 run');
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('c')
      }, 3000)
    })
  });
  
  return from([
    webserverA_req1,
    webserverA_req2, 
    webserverA_req3
  ])
    .pipe(
      concatAll((msg) => of(msg))
    )
});

const webserverB_req = (x) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('webserver B request run');
    setTimeout(() => {
      // console.log(x);
      resolve(x + ' processed')
    }, 9000)
  })
};

source.subscribe(
  x => {
    webserverB_req(x);
  },
  err => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('complete')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here could be one approach:

```js
from(requestsToA)
  .pipe(
    // Sending all the requests sequentially
    concatAll(),

    // Send each `aResponse` to `B`, still sequentially
    concatMap(aResponse => service.sendResponseToBServer(aResponse))
  )
```

If `aResponse2` arrives before the inner observable created for `aResponse1` completes, it will be added to a queue and removed from it when that observable completes, so you can be sure that every request will be sent once at a time.

Comment: you are awesome